# Executing commands using Button widget in Perl-Tk

Tags: linux, perl, perltk

```
#!/usr/local/bin/perl
use Tk;
# Main Window
$mw = new MainWindow;
$label = $mw -> Label(-text=>"Hello World") -> pack();
$button = $mw -> Button(-text => "Quit",
                -command => sub { exit }) -> pack();
MainLoop;
```

In this code when the button `$button` is pressed it closes the program. Because it executes the exit command. I want to modify the code so that when the user clicks on the button it will flush the iptables rule (`iptables -F`). How can I do this?

I tried this:

```
$button = $mw -> Button(-text => "Flush the rules",
                    -command => system ( iptables -F )) -> pack();
```

Why isn't this working? Should I have to make a subroutine for it (then writing the `iptables -F` command there) and then call that subroutine? Can't I directly put the command as I did in above code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to specify a code reference - a callback - which will be executed when the button is pressed, so yes you should place your system call in a `sub { }`.

What you've written is a call to system() at the point that the Button is defined, so you're specifying the return value from system() as the coderef for the callback - which won't work.  The system() function will be called when Button is defined, not when its pressed - which isn't what you want.

Comment: @The system() function will be called when Button is defined.
You mean if I execute the program then the rules will be flushed at the time when Button was defined, right?

Comment: I had a [similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5947681/734153). [This post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2620461/do-i-always-have-to-provide-tkxs-command-argument-an-anonymous-subroutine#2622318) elaborates on Martin's explanation